# How to determine if the value of datetime is valid(full date) or it is in year only?

Tags: c#, datetime

**DATETIME Value 1980**

I have this code to retrieve a DateTime from sql

```
string startDate = ed.IDAFrom != null ? Convert.ToDateTime(ed.IDAFrom).ToShortDateString() : "";
```

**EDIT**

*Note: The Date here is Year Graduated (must be in full date)*

I have a datepicker in my view(so the date is in full date right?).. What if the user forgot the date when he graduate so the user will be edit the datepicker to year only.

What I want to achieve here is if the user encode full date or year I want to get the value of `YEAR` if the user encode full date.

Hope it clears.

Thanks.

**Code**

```
foreach (var ed in exams)
        {
            int rowId = i;
            string startDate = ed.IDAFrom != null ?Convert.ToDateTime(ed.IDAFrom).ToShortDateString() : "";
            string endDate = ed.IDATo != null ? Convert.ToDateTime(ed.IDATo).ToShortDateString() : "";
            string InclusiveDates = startDate + " - " + endDate;
           rowsObj[i] = new { id = rowId, cell = new object[] { rowId, InclusiveDates } };
            i++;
        }
```

Comment: What data type is `ed.IDAFrom`? Is it stored in the database as a string?

Comment: How about `bool isYearOnly = (ed.IDAFrom != null) && (ed.IDAFrom.Trim().Length == 4);`

Comment: @krillgar datetime datatype....

Comment: @CodingYoshi its full date.

Comment: @Blorgbeard If the user encoded in full date I want to get the year only. if the user encode Year then its ok.

Comment: If it's a sql `datetime` then it is not "year only". What RDBMS is this?

Comment: Can you [edit] your post and add a fully self-contained code snippet that we can copy and paste into Visual Studio, run, and see the error you're getting?

Comment: @KiRa So my answer does not solve the issue? Then I am not understanding your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to display the year only if it is in full date.

```
DateTime value;

if(DateTime.TryParse(ed.IDAFrom, out value))
{
    Int year = value.Year;
}
```

If you care about culture:

```
CultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"); // Or whichever culture you need
if (DateTime.TryParse(ed.IDAFrom, culture, DateTimeStyles.None, out value))
{
    int year = value.Year;
}
```

If the user has the option to either enter year only or a full date, use this method:

```
public static string GetDateTime(string value)
{
    DateTime date;
    string dateString = ""; // Empty by default

    // If full date is given, this will succeed
    if (DateTime.TryParse(value, out date))
    {
        dateString = date.ToShortDateString();
    }
    // If only year is given then this will succeed
    else if (DateTime.TryParseExact(value,
            "yyyy",
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            DateTimeStyles.None,
            out date))
    {
        dateString = date.ToShortDateString();
    }

    return dateString;
}
```

**EDIT**

Now that you have added some more code to your question, here is how to do it using Linq:

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
var rows = list.Select(exam =>
{

    string inclusiveDates = string.Format("{0} - {1}", GetDateTime(exam.IDAFrom), GetDateTime(exam.IDATo));
    return new
    {
        Id = ++i,
        Cell = new object[] { ++j, inclusiveDates }
    };
})
.ToList();
```

**And here is an example usage**

```
class Program
{
    public class Exam
    {
        public string IDAFrom { get; set; }
        public string IDATo { get; set; }
    }

    public static string GetDateTime(string value)
    {
        DateTime date;
        string dateString = ""; // Empty by default

        // If full date is given, this will succeed
        if (DateTime.TryParse(value, out date))
        {
            dateString = date.ToShortDateString();
        }
        // If only year is given then this will succeed
        else if (DateTime.TryParseExact(value,
                "yyyy",
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                DateTimeStyles.None,
                out date))
        {
            dateString = date.ToShortDateString();
        }

        return dateString;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var list = new List<Exam> { new Exam { IDAFrom = "1999", IDATo = null },
        new Exam { IDAFrom = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(), IDATo = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5).ToShortDateString() } };
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        var rows = list.Select(exam =>
        {

            string inclusiveDates = string.Format("{0} - {1}", GetDateTime(exam.IDAFrom), GetDateTime(exam.IDATo));
            return new
            {
                Id = ++i,
                Cell = new object[] { ++j, inclusiveDates }
            };
        })
        .ToList();


        foreach (var item in rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", item.Id.ToString(), item.Cell[0], item.Cell[1]);
        }
        Console.Read();

    }
}
```

Comment: I see that, why does this answer not answer your question?

Comment: Sorry.I test you code and apply it to the added code above.

Comment: @kira did this answer your question or the issue is still there?